# Azure Github App Deployment Error: Publish profile does not contain kudu URL

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I had this error and I saw [many people had the same error](https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/issues/28) when using Azure's automated deployment pipeline feature on GitHub. I had linked my GitHub repository to my App Service through a Deployment Pipeline directly on Azure's portal. Everything seemed to have worked fine, but on the GitHub Actions page, I saw the following error:

```
Failed to fetch credentials from Publish Profile. For more details on how to set publish profile credentials refer https://aka.ms/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows
```

and

```
Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Publish profile does not contain kudu URL
```

So, here I'll formally post the solution to this bug for anyone else experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 10):

This solution comes from [the folks on this thread](https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/issues/28), so I don't take any credit for coming up with this solution.

As insinuated by the latter error message, Azure doesn't accept the `publishURL` in the Deployment Credentials. By default, when you set up the automated pipeline, a GitHub Secret is created in your repository. It's called something like `AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_012345...` and it contains the Deployment Credentials. There is one URL you have to change in this profile to make it work. In short, this is what you have to do:

1. Get the Deployment Credentials file from your Azure Portal in the Deployment Center
2. Change the `publishURL` next to `publishMethod="MSDeploy"`. It should be `publishURL="your-app-service.scm.azurewebsites.net"`.
3. Copy that Deployment Credentials text into your Azure GitHub secret's `Value` on your GitHub repository, and re-run the failed job.

### A More Detailed Explanation

To get the text of the Deployment Credentials, which you must edit afterwards, you must go to the `Azure Portal -> your-app-service -> Deployment Center -> Deployment Credentials -> Get publish profile`. If you're having trouble with that, the same process is better explained at the bottom of [the document linked in the first error](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/assets/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows.md). Make sure you don't hit `Reset Publish Profile` after you do this because it will change the password used in your Deployment Credentials and you will have to do all this again.

Once you have this document, open it in a text editor. You have to change the `publishURL` field in the `publishProfile` with `profileName="your-app-service - Web Deploy"` and `publishMethod="MSDeploy"`. Instead of the URL like `foo-bar.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net:123`, put the following with your actual app service title: `your-app-service.scm.azurewebsites.net`.

Now copy all that text, navigate to the GitHub Secret called something like `AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_012345...`, and click `Update` next to the name. Paste the new Deployment Credentials into the `Value` box and click `Update secret`.

Now you're done. Navigate to GitHub Actions, click on the failed job, and click `Re-run jobs` at the top right to get it going again.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. While quite a few others had provided the same answer, you helped with the steps. For beginners on CICD these steps are really useful.

Comment: Agreed, thanks so much - solved it for me as well.